# Java - Make a java program run on a webpage

Tags: java, html

Does anyone know how I can make a java program run on a webpage?  I know many browsers now days do not support Java for security risk, but say I was using an older Java version like Java 6.

What would I have to do to get it to run on a webpage?  Of course saying "Allow" or "Run Program" whenever the user clicks a button is alright.  I cannot use Javascript for this.

Thank you

Comment: older java = even LESS secure. basically, you can't. browser security restrictions exist for a reason, and java has been a festering pile of security problems from day 1. the sooner it's utterly eliminated as a "front-end" for websites, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, apart from Applets, is [Java Web Start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/):

> Java Web Start software provides the power to launch full-featured
>   applications with a single click. Users can download and launch
>   applications, such as a complete spreadsheet program or an Internet
>   chat client, without going through lengthy installation procedures.
>
> With Java Web Start software, users can **launch a Java application by
>   clicking a link** in a web page. The link points to a Java Network
>   Launch Protocol (JNLP) file, which instructs Java Web Start software
>   to download, cache, and run the application.

If you are planning to do something very CPU consuming is better to use Java Web Start. But if you need some JavaScript And Java interaction it would be better to use the old Applets.

If you are worried about browsers blocking or not supporting Java Applets, then Java Web Start is again a better option.

The following links may be of interest to you:

- [Java Web Start (Jnlp) Hello World Example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-web-start-jnlp-hello)
- [Java SE 6: Migrating Applets to Java Web Start Applications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/applet-migration-139512.html)

Answer (score 1):

These things are called Applets. They are considered to be a bit old technology but they are still used at some places.

You can find a tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)